# How to replace Lodash's _.countBy with only ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

Take the below array of arrays
`const data = [[150, 1], [300, 2], [430, 1]]`

With Lodash's `countBy` I could do `_.countBy(row => row[1])` and it would return an object like so `{"1": 2, "2":1}`. It basically counts the occurrences and puts it in an object. How can I do the same with ES6 syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple loop, get the key from calling the callback, and assign key/value pair to the result object:

```js
function countBy(data, getKey) {
    let count = {};
    for (let row of data) {
        let key = getKey(row);
        count[key] = (count[key] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return count;
}

const data = [[150, 1], [300, 2], [430, 1]]
console.log(countBy(data, row => row[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a pretty easy job for map reduce.  The following function accepts an array and selector parameter.  The selector parameter is passed to map to retrieve the items to count.  Reduce is used to accumulate the results by starting with an empty object literal and on each pass incrementing the value for the given key.

```js
function countBy(ary, selector) {
  return ary.map(selector)
    .reduce((acc, cur) => { acc[cur] = (acc[cur] || 0) + 1; return acc; } ,{});
    // fancy spread version:
    // .reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: (acc[cur] || 0) + 1 }) ,{});
}
// view console.log for result
console.log(countBy([[150, 1], [300, 2], [430, 1]], x => x[1]));
```